# <a href> Post request always returns to wrong URL Angular

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

Im trying to execute a like POST request with a  in angular. The url gets filled in correctly as you can see

```html
<a href="http://dressfriends.app/en/like/product/1006" target="_parent" df-like-product="" class="icon-like trigger animated v-a-m active" data-id="1006" data-type="product" ng-class="{active:product.liked_by_user}"></a>
```

In the code it looks like this

```html
<a href="##product.like_url##" target="_parent" df-like-product class="icon-like trigger animated v-a-m" data-id="##product.id##" data-type="product" ng-class="{active:product.liked_by_user}"></a>
```

But everytime it gives a 405 method not allowed (http://dressfriends.app) and returns to http://dressfriends.app

I do the exact samething with PHP without angular and this works

```html
<a href="{{ $product->present()->likeUrl }}" df-like-product class="icon-like trigger animated v-a-m {{ ($currentUser and $product->hasLiked($currentUser->id)) ? 'active' : '' }}" data-id="{{ $product->id }}" data-type="product"></a>
```

Anyone an idea?

Comment: A `a href` link is always retrieved via GET. If you want to POST to it, you'll need to use a form or ajax.

Comment: But in another view is use PHP laravel blade and there it works with an a href? what's the difference?

Comment: Without that code, I couldn't say. Or you might have a GET route defined for it.

Comment: Route::any is used it's laravel

Comment: I edited the post with the php

Answer (score 0):

Angular in not PHP. In order to solve this. you will need to use some service. Most popular are $http and $resource.

in case you choose $http service, you need to make

in somefile.html

in controller you will have something like this:

$scope.someFunction = function(){

$http.post(url, data, config)
   .then(
       function(response){
         // success callback
       }, 
       function(response){
         // failure callback
       }
    );
}

I recommend you to try to find tutorial for this like:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

https://www.sitepoint.com/creating-crud-app-minutes-angulars-resource/
...